# Tag html width overflow-y and fancybox scroll

Tags: html, jquery, css, fancybox

I apologize in advance for possible mistakes in English.

My question is next. In my style.css, html tag have propertie overflow-y:scroll. Farther i'm connect fancybox v3. When i call fancy modal, it is opened correct. But window doesn't fixed by center, because fancy inherite overflow-y:scroll from html tag. How do i fix this? When fancy is opened scrollbars should don't show to me.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply change the CSS-definition via jQuery or something when opening the modal, then revert to "scroll" when closing it. Something like this...

```
$('[data-fancybox]').fancybox({
    afterShow: function( instance, slide ) {

        $('html').css('overflow-y','inherit');

    },
    afterClose: function( instance, slide ) {

        $('html').css('overflow-y','scroll');

    }
});
```